# ASP.NET CompareValidator compare against sub control

Tags: asp.net, textbox, validation, comparevalidator

I have a custom control "FieldGroup" which contains an asp:TextBox and some other functionality. The asp:TextBox is exposed through a public property "TextBox".

On the page that uses my FieldGroup I am having a password entry which means I have two of them and I want to use a CompareValidator to confirm that the values are the same. I could do this with a CustomValidator but I would like to make use of the CompareValidator's client side script.

I tried setting the ControlToValidate="fieldA.TextBox" and the ControlToCompare="fieldB.TextBox" but that is not working. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Do you have a snippet to show us?  I'm thinking that you "might" have to use the `FindControl` method to accomplish what you need.  You can always "modify" your compare validator from the code behind for more flexability... IE write some logic to find the control you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never...

Apply the ValidationPropertyAttribute to the user control class.